# How to run all modules in a folder?

Tags: python-3.x

```
/machine_learning
dtree.py
lr.py
nb.py
svm.py
/main.py
```

Each python file contains one class of machine learning method. In the main.py, import machine_learning as ml, so calling each method like

```
model = ml.py_name.model_name()
```

Is there a way to let me build a list containing all the model classes like

```
[ml.svm.svm_ml(), ml.nb.naivebayes(), ml.lr.logisticregression(), ml.dtree.decisiontree()]
```

I tried

```
ml_list = [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules(['machine_learning'])];
print(ml_list);
#["dtree","lr","nb","svm"]
```

Comment: Can you show us your code that actually tries importing these modules you found through `pkgutil.iter_module`?

Comment: Spelling, formatting

Answer (score 0):

1. import all models you need -> *from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier*
2. creat list *models=[]*
3. add models to list -> *models.append(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3))*
4. split your data to train test
5. use for loop to fit your data to models

for the model in models:
    model.fit(X, Y)